# Python - Trying to find if a sikuli script is running at the moment

Tags: python, sikuli, findwindow, sikuli-x

So I have a sikuli script running which monitors and executes a said action every 10 minutes continuously. However for various reasons sometimes the run is interrupted and there is no way to alert if the script stops running.

So I tried running a python script, which would monitor the window of the sikuli IDE. When the script runs, the window is no longer visible. So if the window is visible again the python script would run a batch file which would trigger the alert required. The following is the script which I made from seeing other examples here in this site:

```
WindowName = "SikulixIDE 1.1.3 - C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Downloads\\testing2.sikuli"

while True:
    try:
        if win32ui.FindWindow(None, WindowName):
            subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\notification.bat'])
            break
    except win32ui.error:
        #print("its not running!")
        continue
```

The problem I am running into with  the above code is, even when the sikuli script is running and the IDE window (one with the WindowName) is not actually visible to me, it still finds it and goes into the if block. I am not sure what's going wrong here, if the window is not visible in Task Manager, FindWindow shouldn't be able to find it, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are trying to do this in very complicated way.

I will strongly suggest to look at '-r' option of sikuli and to write only one sikuli script that will handle exceptions by itself and will not need monitoring.

In this case if you really need additional monitoring for the script it will be easier since you can look for process with specific command line(instead of visible window)